# get the html of the child div if the checkbox in the parent div has been checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="chkBox20">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box20" name="rooms[]" value="20" class="box"/>                                                    
    <div class="specialprice2" style="float:left;">68.00</div>
</div>

<div id="chkBox21">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box21" name="rooms[]" value="21" class="box"/>                                                   
    <div class="specialprice2" style="float:left;">68.00</div>
</div>

<div id="chkBox22">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box22" name="rooms[]" value="22" class="box"/>                                                   
    <div class="specialprice2" style="float:left;">155.00</div>
</div>
```

Some or none of those checkboxes might be checked.

If some of the boxes are checked, I have script that display the sum for checked checkboxes.

What I am trying now is to update the result if the user check or uncheck any of the checkboxes.

Here is the javascript that I have now:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var sum = 0;
 $('.specialprice').each(function(i, el) {
     sum += parseInt($(el).html());
     if(sum){
         thesum = sum.toFixed(2);
     }
 });

 sumPerRoom = (thesum * <?php echo $searchQueryNumOfDays;?>);
 formatedSumPerRoom = sumPerRoom.toFixed(2);
 $('.newprice').append(thesum +" &euro; x Evenings:  <?php echo $searchQueryNumOfDays ;?> = "+formatedSumPerRoom+" &euro;");
});
// above part work just fine, problem is bellow. 
//I guess that bellow I should try something with child div 
//but i don't know how to do it
$(".box").click(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('.specialprice2').each(function(i, el) {
    sum += parseInt($(el).html());
    if(sum){
        thesum = sum.toFixed(2);
    }
});        
    alert(thesum);  
});
```

Needles to say the sum alert the sum of all divs, and i want only the clicked ones.

If someone can help me to alert or to console log the updated price, I will find my way from there.

Regards, John

Comment: ` id="chkBox"21"` you do realise this is invalid html right?

Comment: yeah,sorry about that...I was cleaning the code, and I guess that i have make that mistake somehow...i will fix that in a minute...

Comment: issue has been sorted out now...thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.box').on('change', function(){
   calculate(); 
});

function calculate(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.box:checked').each( function(){
        var price = parseFloat($(this).next('.specialprice2').text());
       total = total + price;
    });
    alert(total.toFixed(2));
}

calculate();
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/kw2H9/1/)

Comment: while the fiddle works great, I get in my code NaN after the first alert...do you have any idea why?

Comment: Have you defined total?

Comment: i struggle to understand why the code in the fiddle works and here it does not....can you point to any clue alex?

Comment: I'll have to see your code. Can you create a fiddle with your whole code?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ here is the fiddle...i am examining if the html is wrong here...

Comment: There is no fiddle. That's the URL to the start page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58355/discussion-between-user2417624-and-alexp).

Answer (score 0):

**NEW:** There is whole code that should work properly as far as `php` will.

```
var thesum = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 var sum = 0;
 $('.specialprice').each(function(i, el) {
     sum += parseInt($(el).html());
     if(sum){
         thesum = sum.toFixed(2);
     }
 });

 sumPerRoom = (thesum * <?php echo $searchQueryNumOfDays;?>);
 formatedSumPerRoom = sumPerRoom.toFixed(2);
 $('.newprice').append(thesum +" &euro; x Evenings:  <?php echo $searchQueryNumOfDays ;?> = "+formatedSumPerRoom+" &euro;");
});

$(".box").click(function(){
    var thesum = sum = 0; //UPDATE
    $('.specialprice2').each(function(i, el) {
        if($(this).parent().find(".box").is(":checked")){ //<---
            sum += parseInt($(el).html());
            if(sum){
                thesum = sum.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    });        
    alert(thesum);  
});
```

**OLD:** This code works perfectly:

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    var thesum = sum = 0; //UPDATE
    $('.specialprice2').each(function(i, el) {
        if($(this).parent().find(".box").is(":checked")){ //<---
            sum += parseInt($(el).html());
            if(sum){
                thesum = sum.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    });        
    alert(thesum);  
});
```

What it does is getting parent of `.specialprice2` element, then finds `.box` element in it and checks if checkbox is checked.

Comment: i get the folllowing error: Uncaught reference error: thesum is not defined.

Comment: I've updated the code so it should work properly now.

Comment: now i did not get any error, however 0 is alerted every single time, no matter what.

Comment: I thought of proper solution but I've put it in wrong place... Here you go now :)

Comment: Hmmm... What browser you are using?